# How to add checkmark on a selected tag in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, web

So im having a hard time doing a system. So the system im making is when you select a tag it should show a checkmark beside it.

Here's the example of what im doing.

Example:
[what im trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq9jN.png) (I dont own the code so I cannot share it)

My Work:

```
              <div class="flex justify-between items-center mb-2">
                <h1 class="text-xl font-semibold text-white">Tags</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="option-select relative mt-1">
                <button
                  id="optionText"
                  class="option-select-btn relative w-full rounded-lg border border-zinc-500/5 hover:border-zinc-500/20 active:border-blue-600 transition-all duration-200 cursor-pointer bg-input px-4 py-2.5 text-left !outline-none"
                  type="button"
                >
                  <span
                    id="selectedOption"
                    class="option-text flex items-center gap-2 truncate text-white"
                  >
                    Select an Option
                  </span>
                  <span
                    class="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-4 text-gray-400"
                  >
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i>
                  </span>
                </button>
                <ul
                  class="options z-[99] absolute mt-2 max-h-60 origin-top-right w-full overflow-auto rounded-md bg-input py-1 text-base shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm"
                  role="listbox"
                >
                  <% config.website.tags.map(a => {%>
                  <li
                    id="tags"
                    class="option-tags relative cursor-pointer select-none px-4 py-2 transition-all duration-200 text-gray-300"
                    role="option"
                  >
                    <a href="/explore/tags/<%= a %>">
                      <span
                        id="results"
                        class="tag-text flex items-center gap-2 truncate font-medium"
                      >
                        <div
                          class="relative w-6 h-6 flex items-center justify-center"
                        >
                          <i class="absolute fa-solid fa-tag opacity-20"></i>
                        </div>
                        <%= a %>
                      </span>
                      <span
                        class="absolute inset-y-0 right-6 flex items-center pl-3"
                      >
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-check text-blue-600"></i>
                      </span>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <% }) %>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Images are not gonna work. Please add the codes here in your question.

Comment: cannot add a direct image, stackoverflow wont allow me cause im new.

Comment: cannot add a direct image : please read my first comment

Comment: Read the description of the tag `web` you used. You also tagged this with `jQuery`, please add the jQuery code you have problems with!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Im asking if you guys know how to do it in jQuery Because I personally don’t know that’s why there’s no jQuery code included